Incomplete output for post-order iterator of a threaded binary tree in C++
I've been trying to write an iterator class for a threaded binary tree in C++. I've tried to modify the Next() member function of ThreadedPostorderIterator class but it keeps printing an incomplete output. I should expect "D E B F G C A" but I see "D E B F" only. What could be the issue with Next()? I attached an MRE below.
main.cpp
#include "ThreadedTree.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    ThreadedTree tree;
    tree.Initialize();

    // The post-order traversal should print "D E B F G C A".
    ThreadedPostorderIterator postorderIterator(tree);
    postorderIterator.Postorder();

    return 0;
}


ThreadedTree.h
#ifndef THREADED_TREE_H
#define THREADED_TREE_H

enum Boolean {FALSE, TRUE};

class ThreadedNode {
    friend class ThreadedTree;
    friend class ThreadedPostorderIterator;
    
  private:
    Boolean LeftThread;
    ThreadedNode* LeftChild;
    char data;
    ThreadedNode* RightChild;
    Boolean RightThread;
  public:
    ThreadedNode() : LeftChild(nullptr), RightChild(nullptr) {} 
    ThreadedNode(char temp, ThreadedNode *left, ThreadedNode *right, Boolean leftT, Boolean rightT)
        : data(temp), LeftChild(nullptr), RightChild(nullptr), LeftThread(leftT), RightThread(rightT) {}

};

class ThreadedTree {
    friend class ThreadedPostorderIterator;
    
  public:
    ThreadedTree();
    void Initialize();
  private:
    ThreadedNode* root;
};

class ThreadedPostorderIterator {
  public:
    char* Next();
    void Postorder();
    ThreadedPostorderIterator(ThreadedTree& tree) : t(tree), CurrentNode(nullptr) {}
  private:
    ThreadedTree& t;
    ThreadedNode* CurrentNode;
};

#endif //THREADED_TREE_H

ThreadedTree.cpp
#include "ThreadedTree.h"
#include <iostream>

ThreadedTree::ThreadedTree() {
    root = new ThreadedNode;
    root->RightChild = root->LeftChild = root;
    root->LeftThread = TRUE;
    root->RightThread = FALSE;
}

//Initialize a complete threaded binary tree consisting of seven nodes
/**The tree should look like this:
                  A
                /  \
               B    C
              / \  / \
             D  E  F  G
*/
void ThreadedTree::Initialize() { 
    // Declare node pointers
    ThreadedNode *A, *B, *C, *D, *E, *F, *G, *H, *I;

    // Initialize root and first node (A)
    root->LeftChild = A = new ThreadedNode('A', nullptr, nullptr, FALSE, FALSE);
    root->LeftThread = FALSE;

    // Initialize the left and right children of A
    A->LeftChild = B = new ThreadedNode('B', nullptr, nullptr, FALSE, FALSE);
    A->RightChild = C = new ThreadedNode('C', nullptr, nullptr, FALSE, FALSE);

    // Initialize the left and right children of B
    B->LeftChild = D = new ThreadedNode('D', nullptr, nullptr, TRUE, TRUE); // D is a leaf node
    B->RightChild = E = new ThreadedNode('E', nullptr, nullptr, TRUE, TRUE);  // E is a leaf node

    // Initialize the left and right children of C
    C->LeftChild = F = new ThreadedNode('F', nullptr, nullptr, TRUE, TRUE);  // F is a leaf node
    C->RightChild = G = new ThreadedNode('G', nullptr, nullptr, TRUE, TRUE);  // G is a leaf node

    // Threading connections (to maintain the threaded binary tree structure)
    D->LeftChild = root;  // Left thread of H points to root (dummy node)
    D->RightChild = B;    // Right thread of H points to D (inorder predecessor)

    E->LeftChild = B;     // Left thread of E points to B (inorder predecessor)
    E->RightChild = A;    // Right thread of E points to A (inorder successor)

    F->LeftChild = A;     // Left thread of F points to A (inorder predecessor)
    F->RightChild = C;    // Right thread of F points to C (inorder successor)

    G->LeftChild = C;     // Left thread of G points to C (inorder predecessor)
    G->RightChild = root; // Right thread of G points to root (dummy node)
}

// Perform postorder traversal and print the nodes
void ThreadedPostorderIterator::Postorder() {
    for (char* ch = Next(); ch; ch = Next()) {
        std::cout << *ch << " ";  // Print data (skip the root/dummy node)
    }
}

//I've been having problems with this member function
//Prints D E B F instead of the post-order sequence D E B F G C A.
char* ThreadedPostorderIterator::Next() {
    if (CurrentNode == t.root) {
        return nullptr; // We've completed the traversal
    }

    ThreadedNode* p = CurrentNode;

    // First call: move to the leftmost node
    if (p == nullptr) {
        p = t.root->LeftChild;
        while (!p->LeftThread || !p->RightThread) {
            if (!p->LeftThread) {
                p = p->LeftChild;  // Move to the leftmost node
            } else {
                p = p->RightChild;
            }
        }
        CurrentNode = p;
        return &p->data;
    }
    //Function ends here and does not advance to handling postorder traversal,
    //which is the next loop

    // Handle postorder traversal
    ThreadedNode* parent = nullptr;
    for (ThreadedNode* q = t.root->LeftChild; q != nullptr;) {
        if (q->LeftChild == p || q->RightChild == p) {
            parent = q;
            break;
        }
        if (!q->LeftThread) {
            q = q->LeftChild;
        } else if (!q->RightThread) {
            q = q->RightChild;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Postorder logic: move from left child to right sibling, then parent
    if (parent) {
        if (parent->LeftChild == p && !parent->RightThread) {
            // If the node is the left child and there is a right sibling, process the right subtree
            p = parent->RightChild;
            while (!p->LeftThread || !p->RightThread) {
                if (!p->LeftThread) {
                    p = p->LeftChild;  // Go to the leftmost node in the right subtree
                } else {
                    p = p->RightChild;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // If the right subtree is fully processed, go back to the parent
            p = parent;
        }
    } else {
        // If no parent is found, traversal is complete
        p = t.root;
    }

    CurrentNode = p;
    if (p == t.root) return nullptr;
    else return &p->data;
}


It seems you are complicating things. At the end if Initialize, run normal postorder, fill elements in a vector as you encounter them. Then in your iterator, just iterate through the vector.
